# d3v4 Timeline chart - upgrading from version 3 to 4

Tags: d3.js

[image]

I have a timeline application - that was using the old d3. I've tried upgrading it and refactoring the codebase - but I've hit a snag with the scale change. This is good as a gantt chart.

//version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/5xsu76ck/1/

//version 4
https://jsfiddle.net/8cy719w0/2/

```
            //scales
            var x =  d3.scaletime()
                    .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd])
                    .range([0, width]);
            var x1 = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .range([0, width]);
            var y1 = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, laneLength])
                    .range([0, mainHeight]);
            var y2 = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0, laneLength])
                    .range([0, miniHeight]);

            var scaleFactor = (1/(timeEnd - timeBegin)) * (width);
```

---

current issue
https://jsfiddle.net/8cy719w0/2/ -- I've managed to get pass some issues - but now got a problem with the brush

```
            //brush
    var brush = d3.brushX()
       .extent([
         [0, 0],
         [width, miniHeight]
       ])
       .on("brush", display);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/KgomDr/cs3jo41b/ -- this is another chart variant -- that may contain the needed brush code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3 version 4 uses d3.scaleTime, so your x variable should be

```
var x =  d3.scaleTime()
.domain([timeBegin, timeEnd])
.range([0, width]);
```

https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#time-scales

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8cy719w0/2/ -- I've managed to get pass some issues - but now got a problem with the brush

Comment: If you have a new question, its best practice to create a new SO question, and leave the original question so that the answer makes sense.

Comment: Its all part of the same problem though --- initially the timescale stopped the chart from working -- completing the conversion from d3v3 to d3v4 -- so its still really the same chart/same problem -- but I see what you mean